# How to write my jquery function in CSS for responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building jquery animation which contains four functions named ani1(),ani2() ani3() and ani4(). Now, I confused about how it's look when deal with responsiveness. Currently, my jquery code running properly. All functions are running one by one and also it looks good on desktop. But I am not sure how to deal with mobile devices. So, I want css code for same animation which I created.

My HTML is as follow:

```
<img class="1st" src="img/imgpsh_fullsize.png" style="width:100%; height:100%;">

<div id="animate1" style="bottom:16.5em;left:33.5em;display:none;">
<img class=" boy" src="img/finger.png" style="" />
</div>  

<div class="2nd" style=" position:absolute; bottom:0;     left:25em;display:none;">
<img class="remote" src="img/remote.png">
</div>

<div class="3rd" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; left:20em;display:none;">
<img class="hand" src="img/hand1.png">
</div>

<div class="4th" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:5em;display:none;">
<img class="ie" src="img/ielogo.png">
</div>
```

And jquery is as follow:

```
    function ani1(){$("#animate1").fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},1000,function(){ 
   $('.1st').animate({'opacity': '0.9','z-index':'2'},1500,
   function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1','z-index':'2'})})});
   //$("#animate1").fadeIn().animate({'margin-bottom':'-3px','margin-left':'0px'},3000)
   $("#animate1").fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},3000)
   .fadeOut();}

   function ani2(){ $(".2nd").fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},1000,function(){
   $('.1st').animate({'opacity':'0.9'},1500,
   function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'})})});  
   $(".2nd").fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},3000)
   .fadeOut();}

   function ani3(){ $('.3rd').fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},1000,function(){ 
   $('.1st').animate({'opacity': '0.9'},1500,
   function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'})})});
   $('.3rd').fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},3000)
   .fadeOut();}

   function ani4(){ $('.4th').fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},1000,function(){ 
   $('.1st').animate({'opacity': '0.9'},1500,
   function(){$('.1st').animate({'opacity':'1'})})});
   $('.4th').fadeIn().animate({'display':'inline-block'},3000)
   .fadeOut();}

    var interval1=[ani1,ani2,ani3,ani4];
    var index =0;
    $(document).ready(function(){
              window.setInterval( function(){ 
                  interval1[index++ % interval1.length]()
                                     },8800);
        clearInterval(interval1);
                                });
```

Currently, it works successfully for desktop. Now, I want to write my all four functions in CSS as such they will run one by one. So, how can we animate 4 jquery functions in CSS as a way that it runs one by one without overlapping?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. Do you want to rewrite your Javascript in pure CSS animation? What exactly is the problem with responsiveness on smaller screens?

Comment: Yes I want to write my same jquery code in css so that it can run when responsiveness.

Comment: I don't think your javascript is causing the responsiveness problem. I would suggest starting by rewriting your html+css so that it works on all screens. You can do that by using relative units and not relying too much on position:absolute. You can then still use jQuery for the opacity/fade effects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the sequencing problem with [animation-delays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay), but be aware that CSS only animates numeric properties, so animating the `display` property will not work.

Comment: Ok but what to do if my .animate() is like below: function(){$('.1st').animate({'margin-left':'5px','margin-bottom':'5px'});} now when we deals with mobile device, how my above code is written in CSS? Because all devices have various widths..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you want, but you can use [vw units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) and [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to make things more dynamic. If you are trying to do complex animations, maybe JS is the way to go. Take a look at the [FLIP](https://aerotwist.com/blog/flip-your-animations/) technique, if performance is your concern.